# Cannot find module "serve-static" | JavaScript | node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, localhost

> I want to create a simple server.js file in node.js which will act as a
>   local server.

I installed the connect module by the following command

```
npm install -g connect
```

And I can see the connect module inside node_modules

Then I tried to install serve-static module as follows

```
npm install -g serve-static
```

It says packages added but I can't see the module inside node_modules.
And when I try to run the following server.js it throws an exception saying
Cannot find module serve-static

**server.js**

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var app = connect();

app.use(serveStatic("../angularjs"));
app.listen(5000);
```

**Error**

```
Error: Cannot find module 'serve-static'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\server.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
```

Comment: Try to Use [express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html) framework instead of connect

Comment: @YouneL thats definetly an opinion

Comment: why are you installing them both globally and not inside your project ?

Answer (score 2):

1- Install them locally

```
npm install connect -S
npm install serve-static -S
```

2- OR Link them into your folder

```
npm link connect
npm link serve-static
```

3- OR Make sure that if the environment variable `NODE_PATH` is set correctly